# How to use different aligning in Extjs Table Layout?

Tags: codeigniter, extjs, text-align

I'm using Extjs 6.0 (with Framework Codeigniter 3.0.3).

I'm trying to get something like this:

```
+---------------------------+-------------+
|  something  |  something  |  something  |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|                    Label A|   Label B   |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I'm using table layout (Label A with colspan 2).

The problem is I need different aligning in Label A and Label B (right and center respectively).

Is there a way to accomplish this?

This is the code:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    title: 'Form Panel',
    bodyStyle: 'padding:5px 5px 0',
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    layout: {
      type: 'table',
      columns: 3
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'label',
        text: '----First Row----',
        padding: 5
    }, {
        xtype: 'label',
        text: '----First Row----',
        padding: 5
    }, {
        xtype: 'label',
        text: '----First Row----',
        padding: 5
    },{
        xtype: 'label',
        text: 'Label A',
        padding: 5,
        colspan: 2,
    }, {
        xtype: 'label',
        text: 'Label B',
        padding: 5
    }],
});
```

For Label A, I've tried adding (without effect):

- align: 'right'
- textAlign: 'right'
- labelAlign: 'right'

If I add:

```
layout: {
  type: 'table',
  columns: 3,
  tableAttrs: {
    style: {
        textAlign: 'right'
    }
  }
}
```

Then both Label A and Label B align to the right, and that's not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following code to align Label A to the right:

```
{
        xtype: 'label',
        text: 'Label A',
        padding: 5,
        colspan: 2,
        style:{
            "float":"right"
        }
    },
```

Comment: YES!! IT WORKS! Thank you so much!
I had problems centering Label B next, but I added textAlign: 'center' in tableAttrs and then just moved Label A.

Answer (score 1):

Labels are somehow special, presumably because they are made for the purpose to be used by `labelable`. A `label` is intended to be used together with a field, and when you click the `label`, that `field` is focused. The `labelable` mixin of the `field` does the aligning (based on the `labelAlign` configuration), and `label` does not always respect the layout you ask for.

While the answer of @Saloo seems to work, it is a hack that may break in other themes and/or older browsers and/or different versions of the framework.

It would be better to use different means of displaying text. I have come to use a [`container` with the `html` configuration](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1-classic/Ext.container.Container.html#cfg-html). With a container, `style:{textAlign:"right"}` works as intended, and since "text-align" is a local CSS setting that does not require the browser to think outside the box, it should be safe enough to use across browsers, across themes, across framework versions.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a better solution. I'd like it to be adaptative to avoid future problems. If you have a code example I'd be glad to try it out. Thanks for your answer!